# how to make a tensorflow database from a list of training data and expected results, and how to structure unique network shapes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm creating a neural network, and have custom made some training data of positions from chess games. I then made a function that splits this data into 797*2 bits of binary input and the expected output as two floats between 0 and 1 (specifically [0, 1], [0.5, 0.5], [1, 0] are the only expected outputs there are). Following is a sample of the variables containing this data:

```
x_train = [[1, 0, 0,... 0, 0, 1],... [0, 0, 0,... 0, 1, 0]] # input: each index contains two positions with 797 bit binary values. couple hundred thousand items in the list.
y_train = [[0, 1], [0.5, 0.5],... [0.5, 0.5]] # expected output: each index contains two digits between 0 and 1 showing which position is better, or are they equal. same size as x_train.
```

However all the tutorials I've found for tensorflow show people using data from their custom-made database, and I have no idea how to structure my data so it can be read by tensorflow. This is what my network will look like (except an input of 797 nodes for each):

[image: image showing a diagram of a neural network with two trees that converge into one]

As you can see, the first 4 layers are split into two parts in which the nodes can't mix, and the 5th layer is connected to every node in the 4th layer(s) just like a normal network. Then it continues as normal until we get our output. If you are interested, it is based off of this research [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.09667.pdf) by Eli (Omid) David, Nathan S. Netanyahu, and Lior Wolf

This is how I've tried to structure this with tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# create the models
model_c = tf.keras.Sequential()
model_c.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(400,)))
model_c.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="sigmoid"))
model_c.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="sigmoid"))
model_c.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="sigmoid"))
model_b = tf.keras.Sequential()
model_b.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(797,)))
model_b.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(600, activation="sigmoid"))
model_b.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(400, activation="sigmoid"))
model_b.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="sigmoid"))
model_a = tf.keras.Sequential()
model_a.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(797,)))
model_a.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(600, activation="sigmoid"))
model_a.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(400, activation="sigmoid"))
model_a.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="sigmoid"))


# compile the models
model_c.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model_b.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model_a.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# run the models
# idk how
```

I really don't know how to make this work, because once again, every tutorial I've found deals with more mundane stuff (like importing a premade database and a simple neural net). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(797,))
model_a = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [tf.keras.layers.Dense(600, activation="sigmoid"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(400, activation="sigmoid"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="sigmoid")]
)
output1 = model_a(input)

model_b = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [tf.keras.layers.Dense(600, activation="sigmoid"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(400, activation="sigmoid"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="sigmoid")]
)
output2 = model_b(input)

x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([output1, output2])
model_c = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="sigmoid"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="sigmoid"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="sigmoid")]
)
output = model_c(x)

model = tf.keras.Model(input, output)

# compile the models
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# run the models
x_train = tf.random.uniform([2000, 797], 0, 2, tf.int32)
y_train = tf.random.uniform([2000, 2])
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Comment: thank you very much! I knew it would be something simple like that (concatenate in this case) but I just had no idea what to do.